# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed when running sudo update-command-not-found

Tags: apt, utf-8

As the question above, when I try to run `sudo update-command-not-found`, I get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-command-not-found", line 26, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 94, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 132, in _fill_commands
    self._parse_single_contents_file(con, f, fp.stdout)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 228, in _parse_single_contents_file
    l = l.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 15: invalid continuation byte
```

I've tried so many ways to get rid of this. The problems seemed to be down to the 'utf-8' issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone with a similar problems, the easiest solution is:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 update-command-not-found
```

And this works for a lot of similar UTF-8 issues related to any kind of installs. Beleave me!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem on a Raspberry Pi after moving from Raspbian stretch to Raspbian buster.

In my case, the root cause is that the apt tool changed the format of files stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/*Contents*` and these are now encoded using the `.lz4` format. Therfore the `update-command-not-found` command can't read them any longer.

This can probably be solved by a new version of "command-not-found" tool (https://code.launchpad.net/command-not-found)